# Is there a way to identify a integer in a string

Tags: mysql, replace

I am needing to replace’”’ after an integer in a string.  Example “Test” set 12” needs to read “Test” 12 inch.

Replace(Example,’ ”’, ‘ inch’) is giving me “Test inch set 12 inch.

Not all integer are in the same place in the string.

Comment: Which language are you gonna use? 
You can use regular expressions to identify and replace.

Comment: You also need to provide more examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the regexp you might be looking for...

```
/(?<=\d+)\"/gm
```

And with Javascript you could try something like this:

```js
const str = `"Test" set 12"`;

str.replace(/(?<=\d+)\"/gm, ' inch');
```

Output:

```
"Test" set 12 inch
```

Explaining the Regexp structure:

`/(?<=\d+)\"/gm`

- **Positive Lookbehind** `(?<=\d+)`

  > Assert that the Regex below matches (This construct may not be supported in all browsers)

  - `\d` matches a digit (equivalent to [0-9])
  - `+` matches the previous token between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `\"` matches the character `"` with index 3410 (2216 or 428) literally (case sensitive)
- **Global pattern flags**

  `g modifier:` **g**lobal. All matches (don't return after the first match)

  `m modifier:` **m**ulti line. Causes `^` and `$` to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of the string)

Comment: For reference, here's the link to the Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/KMux7D/4